# Timeout calling TryUpdateModelAsync on ASP.NET Core 3.1 app in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application that is deployed to a Windows Azure App Service with the ASP.NET Core 3.1 site extension. I get a "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server." error whenever I do a POST to the web application and call TryUpdateModelAsync. I enabled remote debugging and determined that is the method that never returns. When I took that method call out and manually updated my entity everything worked. Also, I don't see this problem when debugging locally.

Here is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/admin/products/{productid:int}/edit")]
public async Task<ActionResult> General(ProductGeneralViewModel model, int productid)
{
    var product = await _db.Products.FindAsync(productid);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        HydrateModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    // Never gets past here and browser shows a 502
    await TryUpdateModelAsync<Product>(product, "Product");

    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("General", new { productid });
}
```

And the Entity Framework model:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Status = ProductStatus.Draft;
        Configurations = new List<ProductConfiguration>();
    }

    public string Container => "products";

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? FeatureImageGalleryId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SeriesId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string ThumbnailPhoto { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string FeaturePhoto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Item #")]
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

    public ProductStatus Status { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public bool AvailableOnline { get; set; }
    public decimal MinimumSize { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FeatureImageGalleryId))]
    public virtual Gallery FeatureImageGallery { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SeriesId))]
    public virtual Series Series { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductConfiguration> Configurations { get; set; }
}
```

This happens with multiple entities. I've also tried to specify specific properties to update using IncludedExpressions in TryUpdateModelAsync and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Your General method is a bit confusing. `TryUpdateModelAsync` will cause the validation rules attached to the Product class to be run against the current state of the object. Since you are passing in product which you just took from the database doesn't that implicitly mean that every validation rule should have already passed?

Comment: @Dennis1679 I'm not sure if TryUpdateModelAsync runs validation, but it looks like ASP.NET Core doesn't have UpdateModel like ASP.NET MVC did.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an issue with ASP.NET Core and lazy loading complex objects in TryUpdateModelAsync.

I found this GitHub issue (it is closed, but the issue was never resolved): https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12866

One workaround that is listed there is to disable lazy loading when calling TryUpdateModelAsync.

```
try
{
    _context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    return await TryUpdateModelAsync(...)
}
finally
{
    _context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```